# C# string nullable

Tags: c#, nullable, nullable-reference-types

Since reference types like string are nullable, what does adding a nullable question mark to the end when declariong a variable actually do?

```
string test = null;
string? test = null;
```

The second line does not show the null as a warning in Visual Studio.

Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but the difference between int and int? is the first cannot be assigned null, but the second can, as adding the ? allows the type to be nullable.  But strings can already be null, so is this just a way to tell the compiler that I know it is a nullable type and accept that it may result in a null?

Comment: @Hardik _"and assign Null value default Null value" - that's not entirely true, even if it behaves like that. It assigns an instance of `Nullable<int>`  with `HasValue` set to `false` to the variable.

Comment: The actual answer is that this does nothing.  Making an already nullable object nullable does nothing more than tell the compiler to ignore the fact that the object could be null.  If you don't have the ? on the end the code will execut exactly the same and allow null to be assigned.